# Value setting in textbox not working in phatomjs2.1.1

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I am trying to set login id and password using jquery v1.6 in phantomjs v2.1.1 , but even after setting the credentials and clicking submit button , page is showing to enter login name and password. My credentials are properly set on page , i know this because i am taking a screenshot of page(see attachment)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoTLy.png)
I have seen all answers relating to this question

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
page.open('example.com', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    console.log("success")
  }
  page.render('home.png');
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    console.log("jquery loaded");
    page.evaluate(function() {
      $('input[id="login-form-username"]').val("abc");
      $('input[id="login-form-password"]').val("adfsdf++");
      $(".aui-button").click();
    });
    page.render('in.png');

    phantom.exit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have reproduced this issue on chrome browser developer console where i loaded webpage then ran lines in page.evaluate function mentioned above.

Comment: `repoduced the issue` - meaning doesn't work there either?

Comment: yes , there is something i have observed that jquery changes the text in textbox but it does not change its html element , i.e. it should also change value attribute of textbox .

Comment: This issue was not due to phatomjs it was due to angular js running on webpage i was working on. Because in case of angular js one need to enter credentials using scope object only

Answer (score 0):

You exit the script too early, right after you've clicked on "log in" button. Try to use a timeout to see if you've been logged in:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  $('input[id="login-form-username"]').val("abc");
  $('input[id="login-form-password"]').val("adfsdf++");
  $(".aui-button").click();
});
page.render('1-before.png');
setTimeout(function(){
     page.render('2-after.png');
     phantom.exit();
}, 5000);
```

Of course this is the most crude way to do this. Ideally you would suscribe to [page.onLoadfinished](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) callback which fires *every* time a page is loaded, in you case twice: 1st time when you open the page to enter credentials and second after you send the form.

Comment: Thanks for your help but none of your suggestion seem to work.